# What are best way to resolve C# unnecessary assignment (IDE0059) warnings?

Tags: c#, warnings

I frequently write code that assigns a value to a local variable but do not use the value.  I do this because it can be useful to examine the value in the debugger (without which I'm not sure how I could examine the variable).  But the C# compiler gives a warning about this.  The suggested potential fixes aren't what I want and I'm wondering what best practices there may be to handle this.  I tried using a discard ('_') but don't seem to be able to examine the value in the debugger.  Suppressing the warning doesn't seem a great idea because there are times when I really do need to clean up the code.  Suggestions welcome.

Example:

```
        [Fact]
        public void TestDuplicateValue()
        {
            string value = "A";
            FieldValue fv1 = new FieldValue(value);
            FieldValue fv2 = new FieldValue(value);

            // Should not throw an exception
            FieldValueCollection fvc = new FieldValueCollection(new FieldValue[] { fv1, fv2 });
        }
```

Comment: Well you kinda got to either use the variable or suppress the warning. Can't really have both.

Comment: You should be able to inspect any variables in scope when a break point is hit.

Comment: Alternatively to use variables, when debugging, you can highlight an expression, such as a method call, and select "QuickWatch..." in the context menu to open a window in which you can inspect the result of that expression. You can also select "Add Watch", which adds an entry for the expression in the watch pane/window.

Comment: You are making no assertion in the test. The whole point of a unit test is that you don't have to inspect values (by debugging) to see if it passes or not.

Comment: @insane_developer Off topic, but the method is testing that an exception does not get thrown.

Comment: @insane_developer Apparently NUnit had an Assert.DoesNotThrow() but this does not exist in XUnit.  My intent is that the test fails if the method does not throw an exception

Comment: @etcetera if your test is not supposed to throw, then you assert for whatever the expected result is. If it ends up throwing then your test is not passing. Most unit tests can potentially fail because of an exception being thrown, and it will most likely vary based on different inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm ... It's really hard to answer questions about things that don't make sense. But you kinda do make sense. I can understand you. Since you really don't want to ignore the warning and I understand why, we have to get creative :)

There really is no way to get rid of the warning message unless you ignore it, or you actually use it.

But there's a solution to everything, even if it's not great, so I give you two options:

**Option 1**

Just comment the line and uncomment it, when you actually need it

**Option 2**

Do something like the following. The Debug.Assert statement breaks execution like a breakpoint, when the given condition is false. Since your fvc variable will never be false, that breakpoint will never be triggered. But still the variable is being used and you get rid of your warning message.

```
    [Fact]
    public void TestDuplicateValue()
    {
        string value = "A";
        FieldValue fv1 = new FieldValue(value);
        FieldValue fv2 = new FieldValue(value);

        // Should not throw an exception
        FieldValueCollection fvc = new FieldValueCollection(new FieldValue[] { fv1, fv2 });
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(fvc != null);
    }
```

**Option 3**

While I'm thinking about it, here's a bonus one. You **comment** that line. But when you're debugging your code, you can copy and paste your instruction into a Watch Window, and can the value of it. Use VisualStudio Menu, Debug/Windows/Watch/Watch1 - Only available while debugging

**Edits**

Replaced uncomment by comment and made it bold

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I like Option 2 (I'll also add a comment why I have put that in the code).  Option 3 is creative, but won't work in cases where "new FieldValueCollection(...)" has side effects that cause its behavior to change with each invocation.